# Modal Image not working for all images

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am displaying some ads from my database through php. I want a modal image to be opened and display the full sized image when the particular image against an ad is clicked. I have used the code provide here http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

This works for the very first ad picture but not others. I am using the above code in the foreach() loop of php in order to make it work against all ad pictures.

Code for the image portion

```
foreach($ads as $ad){
<img id="myImg" src="'.base_url("uploads/".$b['images']).'" class="img-    responsive">
}
```

This displays the picture from the database, what I want is to show the enlarged picture in modal.

Comment: Without your code we cannot see what goes wrong. Using the same `id` for multiple images, for instance? I cannot tell.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've added the code for the image part

Comment: Yes, as I thought, you're reusing the id `myImg`. in priciple id's should be unique in your html code. Try to add something like an image number to the id, and then use the correct image id when you call the modal.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that worked.

Comment: Nice! That's great. Sometimes life can be easy. :-)